# How to merge and synchronize the audio with the processed video for real time streaming?

Tags: c, audio, video, ffmpeg, yolo

I am detecting objects on a RTMP video+audio stream. The output, object detected video stream doesn't contain audio in it. How to merge the audio back to the output for real-time video+object streaming output ?

I am  using YOLO in darknet C framework. The FPS is 40. Also the output stream needs to be in 25-30 FPS.

Comment: No code? Can't give any suggestions without it.

Comment: As of now I have used YOLO object detection in C language. If you can suggest with some code or snippet it will be great. Thanks ! https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet